# Hibernate error - QuerySyntaxException: administrator is not mapped error

Tags: java, eclipse

full error message:

> ```
> 11:49:51,896 INFO [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 
> javax.ejb.EJBException: 
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
>     administrator is not mapped [SELECT ad FROM administrator ad WHERE ad.adminID='123' AND ad.Password='123']
> ```

```
@Stateless
public class ManageAdministrator implements ManageAdministratorRemote {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "JPADB")
    private EntityManager entityManager;    

    public ManageAdministrator() {
    }

    public Administrator createAdministrator(Administrator adminID )
    {
        entityManager.persist(adminID);
        System.out.println("Inside create administrator");
        entityManager.flush();
        return adminID;
    }

    public List retrieveAllAdministrators()
    {
        String q = "SELECT ad from " + Administrator.class.getName() + " ad";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(q);
        List administrators = (List) query.getResultList();
        return  administrators;
    }

    @Override
    public Administrator adminLogin(Administrator adminID) {
        try {
            String q ="SELECT ad FROM administrator ad WHERE ad.adminID='" 
                     + adminID.getAdminID() +"'"
                     + " AND ad.Password='"
                     + adminID.getPassword() +"'";

            Query query = entityManager.createQuery(q);
            query.setMaxResults(1);
            //query.setParameter("logInEmail", admin.getLogInEmail());
            System.out.println(q);
            return (Administrator) query.getSingleResult();
         } 
         catch(NoResultException e) 
         {
                return null;
         }
    }

    @Override
    public int stringToInt(String word) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
```

may I Know what is the cause of this error ?

Comment: In persistence.xml is the Administrator class available?

Comment: Indeed, can you post persistence.xml, spring configuration and Administrator entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your entity class seems to be Administrator (with capital A at start) while in your query you use administrator (with lower case a at the start).JPA queries are case-sensitive.

Change this line of code:

```
String q ="SELECT ad FROM Administrator ad WHERE ad.adminID='"
```